# Docker flask server container cannot be accessed via host

Tags: docker, server, network-programming

Unfortunately the web is littered with similar questions though they are all slightly different and some involve virtual machines. Here is my setup:

Mac osx 10.13.2
Docker 18.06.0-ce

I have a very simple flask restful server that, when run, I can access via:
http://127.0.0.1:8015/Outlier/username/100/
And I get a numerical result.

I've set up a Docker image with the server application above and requirements flask, flask-restful and requests. When I run a container of that image I can access the results via:

```
docker exec <container id> curl http://127.0.0.1:8015/Outlier/username/100/
```

The issue is that when I access http://127.0.0.1:8015/Outlier/username/100/
via chrome, on the host, I get the message:

> This page isn’t working
>   127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I understand that the container is running on its own ip:port and that on the host I have to correctly reach that location.

```
docker ps <container id>
```

For PORTS shows

> 0.0.0.0:8015->8015/tcp

I made sure that the Dockerfile does EXPOSE 8015:8015 (so the host and container ports match)

```
docker inspect <container id>
```

Returns a bunch of details including one HostIp which is empty. According to this useful [docker post](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-localhost-inside-the-container-itself/43203/7) I have to look at the 'Gateway' setting which in my case is 172.17.0.1. Anyway, I've tried the following on my host machine via chrome(and curl) without any success. What other setting(s) should I set? This should not be this time consuming...

http://localhost:8015/Outlier/username/100/ 
http://0.0.0.0:8015/Outlier/username/100/ 
http://127.0.0.1:8015/Outlier/username/100/ 
http://<192.168.1.75 ip of my host via ifconfig>:8015/Outlier/username/100/ 
http://172.17.0.1:8015/Outlier/username/100/ 
http://<172.17.0.2 which is the IP address according to docker inspect>:8015/Outlier/username/100/

Any pointers?

Comment: what is the cmd you use to start the container?

Comment: docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id

Comment: For the first question, I used: docker run -p 8015:8015 username/imagename  For the second question, the answer is 172.17.0.2 which I've already tried. I can confirm that my firewall (system preferences -> security -> firewall) is OFF for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this [posting](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2670) you will see that out of the box Docker does not work as expected on OSX, i.e. if you run a server app in a container, you will not be able to access it on your host machine without some setup. Since I was running out of space on my Mac and have a linux server at home, I resolved this issue by using Docker in Linux (mint). The solution requires absolutely no tweaks. Docker in Linux works as you (I) would expect.

Lastly, here is a link to a very useful set of post install [settings to consider when you run Docker on a Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds).